# Placing a value at the bottom of a channel?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

In Clojure(Script), is there anyway to jam a value at the bottom (as opposed to the top) of a channel so that the next time it is taken from (for example by using `<!` inside a go block), it is guaranteed that that the value you jammed into it will be the one that is received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is any easy way to do this. You may be able to implement your own type of buffer, as in [buffers.clj](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/buffers.clj), and then instantiate your channel using that buffer:

```
(chan (lifo-buffer 10))
```

For example you could create a buffer that works like a LIFO queue:

```
(deftype LIFOBuffer [^LinkedList buf ^long n]
  impl/UnblockingBuffer
  impl/Buffer
  (full? [this]
    false)
  (remove! [this]
    (.removeFirst buf))
  (add!* [this itm]
    (when-not (>= (.size buf) n)
      (.addFirst buf itm))
    this)
  (close-buf! [this])
  clojure.lang.Counted
  (count [this]
    (.size buf)))

(defn lifo-buffer [n]
  (LIFOBuffer. (LinkedList.) n))
```

Beware, though, that this solution relies on implementation details of `core.async` and may break in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two channels, imagine one is called `first-class` and the other is called `economy`. You write a `go-loop` that just recurs and calls `alts!` (or `alts!!`) on the two channels, but with the `:priority` option for `first-class`. Then you put values into `economy` as your "normal" input channel, and when you want a value to jump the line, you put it into `first-class`.